# Немогу понять почему обьект не "растягивается"?

Tags: qml

Задал два квадрата и привязал размер текста к размеру квадрата

Только вот в первом квадрате (бирюзовом) текст и ввод не растягиваются
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот не знаю как сделать динамическую подстройку элементов ввода и текста

вот код :

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.4

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#89cdf1"
        
        x: parent.width/100;
        y:parent.height/10;
        
        width: parent.width/4
        height: parent.height/1.2
        
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
        
        anchors
        {
            leftMargin: 10
            rightMargin: 10
            bottomMargin: 10
        }
        
        
        
        Grid{
            id: gridLayout
            x:0
            y:0
            
            rows: 2
            columns: 2
            //            anchors.centerIn: parent
            columnSpacing: 10
            rowSpacing: 10
            
            Text {
                id:text1
                color: "#00000f"
                
                text: "ширина1:"
                font.family: "Helvetica"
                font.pixelSize: parent.width /10;
            }
            
            // Область с TextInput
            Rectangle {
                id:rectangle2
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                color: "white"
                width:  parent.width /2;
                height:  parent.height /3;
                
                TextInput {
                    id: textInput3
                    color: "#151515";
                    selectionColor: "green"
                    font.pixelSize: parent.width /10;
                    font.bold: true
                    
                    width: parent.width/3;
                    height:  parent.height /3;
                    
                    maximumLength: 8
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    focus: true
                    validator : RegExpValidator { regExp : /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ } //ввод только чисел !!
                    
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    //                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    //                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    cursorVisible : true
                    
                    
                    //                /* По нажатию клавиши Enter передаём информацию
                    //                 * из TextInput в элемент ListView
                    //                 * */
                }
            }
            
            Text {
                id:text3
                color: "#00000f"
                
                text: "ширина2:"
                font.family: "Helvetica"
                //                font.pointSize: parent.width/(4*4);
                
            }
            
            // Область с TextInput
            Rectangle {
                id:rectangle3
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                color: "white"
                width:  parent.width /2;
                height:  parent.height /3;
                
                TextInput {
                    id: textInput4
                    color: "#151515";
                    selectionColor: "green"
                    font.pixelSize: parent.width /10;
                    font.bold: true
                    
                    width: parent.width/3;
                    height:  parent.height /3;
                    
                    maximumLength: 8
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    focus: true
                    validator : RegExpValidator { regExp : /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ } //ввод только чисел !!
                    
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    //                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    //                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    cursorVisible : true
                    
                    
                    //                /* По нажатию клавиши Enter передаём информацию
                    //                 * из TextInput в элемент ListView
                    //                 * */
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle1
        color: "#5555f1"
        
        x:(parent.width - ((parent.width/4)*1.05));
        y:parent.height/10;
        width: parent.width/4
        height: parent.height/1.2
        //        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        
        
        anchors
        {
            leftMargin: 10
            rightMargin: 10
            bottomMargin: 10
        }
        Text {
            // (1) identifier
            id: thisLabel
            // (2) set x- and y-position
            x: 24; y: 16
            // (3) bind height to 2 * width
            height: 2 * width
            // (4) custom property
            property int times: 24
            // (5) property alias
            property alias anotherTimes: thisLabel.times
            // (6) set text appended by value
            text: "Greetings " + times
            // (7) font is a grouped property
            font.family: "Ubuntu"
            font.pixelSize: parent.width /10
            // (8) KeyNavigation is an attached property
            KeyNavigation.tab: otherLabel
            // (9) signal handler for property changes
            onHeightChanged: console.log('height:', height)
            // focus is need to receive key events
            focus: true;
            // change color based on focus value
            color: focus?"red":"black"
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Размер полей завязан на размер Grid'а, который никак не меняется

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Спасибо @Croessmah

в общем добавил рамер грида и всё стало меняться

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.4

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#89cdf1"

        x: parent.width/100;
        y:parent.height/10;

        width: parent.width/4
        height: parent.height/1.2

        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight

        anchors
        {
            leftMargin: 10
            rightMargin: 10
            bottomMargin: 10
        }



        Grid{
            id: gridLayout
            x:0
            y:10;
            width:  parent.width;
            height: parent.height/3

            rows: 2
            columns: 2
            //            anchors.centerIn: parent
            columnSpacing: 10
            rowSpacing: 10

            Text {
                id:text1
                color: "#00000f"

                text: "ширина1:"
                font.family: "Helvetica"
                font.pixelSize: parent.width/10;
            }

            // Область с TextInput
            Rectangle {
                id:rectangle2
                y: parent.height /100;

                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                color: "white"
                width:  parent.width /3;
                height:  parent.height /7;

                TextInput {
                    id: textInput3
                    color: "#151515";
                    selectionColor: "green"
                    font.pixelSize: parent.width /5;
                    font.bold: true

                    width: parent.width/3;
                    height:  parent.height /3;

                    maximumLength: 8
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    focus: true
                    validator : RegExpValidator { regExp : /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ } //ввод только чисел !!

                    anchors.fill: parent
                    //                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    //                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    cursorVisible : true


                    //                /* По нажатию клавиши Enter передаём информацию
                    //                 * из TextInput в элемент ListView
                    //                 * */
                }
            }

            Text {
                id:text3
                color: "#00000f"

                text: "ширина2:"
                font.family: "Helvetica"
                //                font.pointSize: parent.width/(4*4);
                font.pixelSize: parent.width /10;

            }

            // Область с TextInput
            Rectangle {
                id:rectangle3
                y:200; // не работает
                x:100; // не работает

                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                color: "white"
                width:  parent.width /3;
                height:  parent.height /7; // 10

                TextInput {
                    id: textInput4
                    y: 20;
                    color: "#151515";
                    selectionColor: "green"
                    font.pixelSize: parent.width /5;
                    font.bold: true

                    width: parent.width/3;
                    height:  parent.height /3;

                    maximumLength: 8
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    focus: true
                    validator : RegExpValidator { regExp : /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ } //ввод только чисел !!

                    anchors.fill: parent
                    //                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    //                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    cursorVisible : true


                    //                /* По нажатию клавиши Enter передаём информацию
                    //                 * из TextInput в элемент ListView
                    //                 * */
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle1
        color: "#5555f1"

        x:(parent.width - ((parent.width/4)*1.05));
        y:parent.height/10;
        width: parent.width/4
        height: parent.height/1.2
        //        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft


        anchors
        {
            leftMargin: 10
            rightMargin: 10
            bottomMargin: 10
        }
        Text {
            // (1) identifier
            id: thisLabel
            // (2) set x- and y-position
            x: 24; y: 16
            // (3) bind height to 2 * width
            height: 2 * width
            // (4) custom property
            property int times: 24
            // (5) property alias
            property alias anotherTimes: thisLabel.times
            // (6) set text appended by value
            text: "Greetings " + times
            // (7) font is a grouped property
            font.family: "Ubuntu"
            font.pixelSize: parent.width /10
            // (8) KeyNavigation is an attached property
            KeyNavigation.tab: otherLabel
            // (9) signal handler for property changes
            onHeightChanged: console.log('height:', height)
            // focus is need to receive key events
            focus: true;
            // change color based on focus value
            color: focus?"red":"black"
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]